# Making master password and storing it

Tags: java, android, authentication

I'm trying to make a password manager app. In which on start you setup a master password that will lead you to the `MainActivity`, where you store other passwords.

How do I store `editText` input for the login?

I see that people are talking about not storing it, and making it encrypted.

Comment: Are you sure? How much i saw its for syncing and adding account, not encrypting passwords

Comment: You should use database if you want to store that

Comment: So, like SharedPreferences should do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

You should use some server side storage for those passwords, as the user can anytime go to app settings and **Clear Data**

That would erase each and every password you've stored encrypted or not.

For starters, you can use [web services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) . Make a small server side application in java or php for the webservices.

You can store in local and on server both. Check local database first, if you don't find the passwords there then check the server, if you do find passwords on the server then sync with your local db. In case user decides to **Clear Data** for that app. Your passwords will still be available on server.

Comment: So what if the user has no connection in a particular moment? Can't use the app? Also, OP is talking about a master password to unlock all the others.

Comment: He can sync ... store in local as well as server. But storing something like passwords ONLY in local is not safe, as the -Clear Data- button can whip everything. Including `SharedPreferences`